# How to trigger events in different components of my React App, using Direct Line component of Microsoft Bot Framework?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, bots, botframework, es6-modules

I have defined a directline.js Component which exports the directLine Object which used by two other components, WebChat.js and OrderPlacing.js.
Whenever I am making directline.postActivity from OrderPlacing.js it is not able to reflect it on to the chatbot. It would be cool if someone helps out.

directline.js

```
....
export const directline = new DirectLine({
  secret: DIRECT_LINE_SECRET
})
```

Webchat.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Chat } from 'botframework-webchat'
import { DirectLine } from 'botframework-directlinejs'
import {directline} from '../directline'

class Webchat extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.directLine = directline
  }
  componentDidMount () {
    let {profileObj } = this.props.user
    this.directLine.postActivity({
      from: { id: profileObj.googleId, name: profileObj.name},
      type: 'event'
    }).subscribe(
        id => { console.log(id)},
        error => console.log('Error posting activity', error)
    )
  }
}
  render () {
    let { profileObj } = this.props.user
    return (
      <div>
          <Chat botConnection={this.directLine} user={{ id: profileObj.googleId, name: profileObj.name}} />

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

OrderPlacing.js

```
...
import {directline} from '../directline'
...
axios.post('...').then(() => {
     this.directLine.postActivity({
    from: { id: user.googleId, name: user.profileObj.name, 
      company_id:user.company_id },
    type: 'orderPlaced'
  }).subscribe(id => console.log(id), (error) => console.log(error))
})
});
...
```

Comment: Hi @Ankit - Can you provide more context? What did you try? What worked? What didn't work? Can you share your complete bot code and React app?

Comment: @nilsw I am trying to create a online ordering chatbot. I have a chatbot which gives the insights while OrderPlacing Page for placing the order. So I am creating a directline object which I am sharing between two components. And on the componentDidMount() of the Webchat Component I am firing a postActivity which makes the chatbot start interacting, while OrderPlacing Page after placing the order I am firing the directline postActivity which informs the chatbot server that the order is placed. So the problem is coming that when the order is placed it is not able to reflect on to the chatbot.

Comment: What is the error that occurs?

Comment: It runs without errors. The only thing is that it does'nt show the dialog, I trigger using the directline.postActivity() from the OrderPlacing.js, Component.

Comment: Hi @AnkitChauhan - Can you share your complete bot code (all lines, all files) here or on a public GitHub repository? I'm unable to reproduce the issue using only the partial snippets.